# Error when building c code with -D

Tags: c, building

I get the following errors when I'm trying to build my c code files with -D. But, if I build it without -D, it works. I don't know why. Thanks. (My machine is ubuntu12.10, 32bit)

```
gcc c1.c c2.c -D DEBUG

/tmp/ccX04EIf.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `g'
/tmp/cc0j9MoU.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my source code:

**global.h**

```
#ifdef DEBUG 
    int g = 23;
    static int init = 1;
#else
    int g;
    static int init = 0;
#endif
```

**c1.c**

```
#include "global.h"
int f() {
    return g + 1;
}
```

**c2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "global.h"

int main() {
    if (!init) {
        g = 37;
    }
    int t = f();
    printf("calling f yields %d\n", t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why a space between `-D` and `DEBUG`?

Comment: @HowChen Does it matter? No.

Comment: @Jost, but he said it works without -D

Comment: @HowChen Mybe my statement is not clear. I mean compiling with -D DEBUG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *define* the variable `g` in the header file, that means it will be defined in all source files that includes the header file.

Instead *declare* it, like

```
extern int g;
```

and then define it in a single source file.

Comment: or add include guards?

Comment: @HowChen Include guards only protects against multiple inclusion in a single translation unit (e.g. source file), not against multiple inclusion in multiple translation units.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand what you mean. Now I change global.h to make sure there is only declaration of g, and move the g definition into c2.c when DEBUG is defined. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two code paths (with and without `DEBUG`) is the initialization of the `g` variable. Without it, it is only a "tentative" definition, and so the symbol is only generated in the file that really uses it, namely `c2.o`.

With initialization it is a real definition of the symbol, and so it is also generated in `c1.o`.

As a rule of thumb, header files should never contain data definitions, only declarations. Data "declarations-only" should be made with the keyword `extern`. You'd then need to define any such symbol in exactly one of your .c files.